# Representing simple mathematics using BNF

Tags: math, bnf

I have written the following BNF "code", which attempts to describe simple mathematics using BNF. The issue I am having is that I have no idea how to add parentheses (brackets).

```
Digit ::= "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9";
Digits ::= <Digit>|<Digit><Digit>;
Number ::= <Digits>|<Digits>.<Digits>;

Addition ::= <Value> + <Value>;
Subtraction ::= <Value> - <Value>;
Multiplication ::= <Value> * <Value>;
Division ::= <Value> / <Value>;
Value ::= <Number>|<Addition>|<Subtraction>|<Multiplication>|<Division>;
```

The other issue is that I'm not sure that the BNF is 100% correct, as the `Value` "description" doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Digit ::= "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9";
Digits ::= <Digit>|<Digit><Digits>;
Number ::= <Digits>|<Digits>.<Digits>;
Operator ::= "+" | "-" | "*" | "/"
Bracket_Left ::= "("
Bracket_Right ::= ")"
Value ::= <Number>|<Bracket_Left><Value><Bracket_Right>|<Value><Operator><Value>
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but should work. Always keep in mind the power of recursion.

Comment: Wow, that's so much simpler than mine! Thanks! Is there a reason you use `Bracket_Left` and `Bracket_Right` instead of inserting them directly into the `Value` definition?

Comment: Actually no that's unnecessary - I just like to separate the elementary definitions and derivative ones :) OCD lol

Comment: It makes sense really, I think I'll keep it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are after operator precedence too, you should use well known method by a recursion (right one in my example):

```
AddSub   ::= <MulDiv> ("+" | "-") <AddSub> | <MulDiv>;
MulDiv   ::= <Brackets> ("*" | "/") <MulDiv> | <Brackets>;
Brackets ::= "(" <AddSub> ")" | <Decimal>;
Decimal  ::= <Integer> "." <Integer> | <Integer>;
Integer  ::= <Digit> <Integer> | <Digit>;
Digit    ::= "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9";
```

and operator precedence is automatically followed by parser, without further intervention. I didn't invent this method, it is there for decades, but I have to admit it's kind of genial.